# How to understand どうかしましたか?

Tags: words, expressions

I could not figure it out. What does どうかしましたか mean?

Comment: What part do you find difficulty?

Comment: The meaning itself.

Comment: I mean, did you try to break it down to words you know? What aspect is what you already know and what isn't? The question now looks like bulk translation and could get closed.

Comment: Did you refer to a dictionary? http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B ←辞書にそのまんま載ってるし

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I find the pserson who seems badly annoyed or being in a state of numbness. If I have entirely no idea about the situation or backgrand, but I can't just stand by himself or herself and I'd like to get around to telling him or her. I usually talk softly to the pserson "どうかしましたか？."

It has very little to do with whether I konw the pserson or not.